# From command line, make perl substitute matches only after a match of another regex

Tags: regex, perl, file

I'm making some mass character replacements inside of comments with multiple matches per line, and this reduces to the problem mentioned in the title. Is there a simple way to do this in a perl one-liner? The simplest way I've thought of so far is to do something like

```
perl -pi e 's/(.*regex1.*)(regex2)/$1replacement/' filename
```

and simply run this until the files stop changing. It seems like there must be a better way to do a one-liner for this.

Example input (the number of columns varies across the files):

```
   /*
    * name     val1     val2
    * foo      2345     23
    * barbaz   34       23456
    */
```

Example output:

```
   /*
    * name.....val1.....val2
    * foo......2345.....23
    * barbaz...34.......23456
    */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
perl -pwe 'if (m#/\*# .. m#\*/#) { 
    s/\w\.*\K( {2,})(?=\S)/ "." x length($1) /eg; }' input.txt > output.txt
```

But be aware that matching comments with regexes is a tricky business. As long as the comments follow your simple style, you should be ok, but watch out for it matching other comments as well.

In this one-liner, I use the flip-flop operator to match between the open and close comment symbols. Inside, it matches any alphanumeric `\w` followed by optional periods, and replaces any spaces (2 or more) following it with periods. The look-ahead at the end is there to prevent it adding on periods after the last word, e.g. `foo....bar.....`

I opted to use `( +)` to capture only spaces, but you may replace that with `(\s+)`. Replacing tabs with periods will be much trickier, though, if you want to preserve the indentation.

**ETA:**

You may wish to make use of the `-i` option to perform in-place edit on files, which is handy when doing multiple files. The safe way is to use backups, e.g. `-i.bak`.

Comment: Doesn't this only do one column? I didn't know about the \K trick.

Comment: The `\K` (mnemonic: keep) is much like a look-behind assertion. No, it produces the output you wanted. Why don't you try it out and see.

Comment: OK, yes, but I changed it to require at least two spaces in a row since this as is causes lots of other comments to get dots.placed.in.them.like.this.

Comment: BTW, I had to use double quotes in the substitution since this code had an error as is.

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to change that.. I'm on windows. You can change `+` to `{2,}` if you only want to match more than 2 spaces.